# Autolayout Resize multiple labels

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, label

I have three labels

[image]

There is a button above each label

I have added constraints for each label : align trailing and leading to button, as well as top space to button

Also, I have set the font size to 14, and Autoshrink Minimum Font Scale to 0.5

I want these three labels to have the same font size and to shrink and expand themselves according to screen size

But unfortunately they differs in their sizes according to the text

Any help? Thanks

Comment: give all label equal height and equal width by selecting all labels

Comment: @Jaimish should i remove the current constraints?

Comment: please give me your current constraints of all label or give me the flow how you give constraints to each label

Comment: @Jaimish for each label I added: 1- Align Trailing Space to button 2-Align Leading Space to button 3- Top space to button

Answer (score 1):

-> Give `fixed width constraint` to all the labels.
 -> Give only `leading space constraint` to first label.
 -> Give only `trailing space constraint` to last label label.
 -> Give `align centre x`(centre horizontally) constraint to middle label.

Comment: is it better to center x the labels to the buttons above them? Instead of leading and trailing space constraints?

Comment: That would be much better if you have already set constraint for button,